# How to solve the error (wrong version number) when call API using cURL

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.3

I have tried to call an intranet API (self-signed) (hosted in openshift) in a docker.

- OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
- curl 7.74.0

I am able receive a response by calling the same API using Postman, and the code snippet generated in Postman could also run successfully in IIS (C# RestSharp, PowerShell - RestMethod)

- The API is host in https
- Accept TLS Protocol: TLS v1.3, TLS v1.2
- bypass proxy

```
--data '' --verbose --insecure > > 

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx:443...
* Connected to servername (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

In the docker, I am able to

- ping the server
- resolve the server hostname to ip address

I am able to receive a response by calling the API

- In Postman
- Using code snippet generated in Postman could also run successfully in IIS (C# RestSharp, PowerShell - RestMethod)
- I am able to call other intranet APIs hosted in another servers.
- In another docker which is host in openshift

Please kindly give some insights on solving the issue

Comment: *"I have tried all recommended solution in the web, but no luck."* - which says exactly nothing what you actually tried and is therefore a useless statement. This error has usually nothing to do with SSL version even though it claims to be. Instead it happens when trying to access a system by HTTPS which returns a plain HTTP response. This might be due to some wrong proxy settings when using curl, accessing the wrong server endpoint ... There are too few information about your setup known though to point out the specific problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the comment, I have updated the question. I am able to receive a response in other means (Postman) using https too, and I have the same proxy settings (by pass proxy) for all environments. But don't know why it won't work in the docker.

Comment: I would recommend that you do a packet capture to find out, what response you actually get back from the server. Hopefully this gives you more insight of what is going wrong. Also, checking the server logs might help.